# How to select text under multiple "div-li-a href" using css in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I want to select the  tag under li.
I have tried with below css:

```js
By.cssSelector("div.grid_10 div.box.round.first.fullpage div.block id.tabs-container a[text()='Active Companies/Filing']"))
```

```html
<div class="grid_10">
 <div class="box round first fullpage">
   <h2>View Theme Information</h2>
   <div class="block ">
     <script type="text/javascript"> $(window).load(function() { $('#loading').hide(); }); </script>
     <div class="block" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
       <div id="loading" style="display: none;">  
        <div id="tabs-container" style="height:500px;">
          <ul class="tabs-menu">
            <li class="">
            <li class="current">
              <a href="#secondtab">Active Companies/Filing</a>
            </li>
```

Please help?

Comment: I see that the 'Active Companies/Filing' is a Hyperlink. Wouldn't it be possible to use `By.LinkText`?

Comment: Tried that, did't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is no function `text()` in `cssSelector`. So using `cssSelector` you can't locate element with the text because there is no way to locate with inner text. You should try using `xPath` as below

```
By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Active Companies/Filing')]"))
```

Or

```
By.xpath("//li[contains(.,'Active Companies/Filing')]"))
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: Able to locate the element using below

By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Active Companies/Filing')]"))

Comment: Also, in case if new tab is added to page or tab gets shifted from second to third then also it should work unless text is changed.
This seems to be better option than CssSelector in second post below.

Thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
By.CssSelector("[href='#secondtab']").Text;
```

If you are getting NoSuchElementExceptions, I notice a isLoading element, you might have to make sure that is loaded before it can find the elements in the tabs.  You might also need to be aware if there are similar elements with the same tags but just not displayed, meaning you might need to make sure you're only looking for displayed elements.

I also just realized you want to find the element by text, not that you want to get the text of that element.  Do you know the element of #secondTab will always have that Text?  Let me know if calling directly to the href at least gets to the element.  Maybe you'll need to do a double verification, where you grab the text of that link then have an if with the text you're looking for before you click it?

Comment: Thanks, It Worked!!
You guessed it right, Page is multi tabbed and i want to click on second tab to perform some operation.

Answer (score -1):

If there is only one link with the text "Active Companies/Filing" then you can go with

```
By.cssSelector(li a[text()='Active Companies/Filing'])
```

Try it. It should work.

Comment: Thanks, but did't worked....there are multiple li elements and controller is not going to this text 





<div id="tabs-container" style="height:500px;">
<ul class="tabs-menu">
<li class="current">
<a href="#firsttab">View Theme Details</a>
</li>
<li class="">
<a href="#secondtab">Active Companies/Filing</a>
</li>
<li class="">
<a href="#thirdTab"> BAF Dispersion </a>
</li>

Comment: @ShaileshGohel have you tried it in your end using cssSelector... there is no function `text()` in cssSelector to use...it is in xpath...